# Java-Mac OS X integration without breaking platform independence

Tags: java, macos, cross-platform

I want my application to integrate Mac OS X better. I've read [Mac OS X Integration for Java](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909) and I've learned I have to import `com.apple.eawt.*` and write some extra code. But, if I do this, my application is not going to work on Windows because of missing reference. I could do this with preprocessor command if I write in C but this is Java. How can I do this without separating the code file into 2 branches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Macify it.](http://simplericity.com/2007/10/02/1191336060000.html)

Answer (score 3):

I used reflection to see if the com.apple.whatever class was there, and if so, I invoked it.

Worked very well, and does not create breaking imports.

Answer (score 2):

I've previously bookmarked these pages which have good advice about tweaking Swing applications for OS X.

- Make Your Swing App Go Native ([Part 1](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/12/08/swing.html), [Part 2](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/01/05/swing.html), [Part 3](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2004/01/29/swing.html))
- Bringing your Java Application to Mac OS X ([Part 1](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac/), [Part 2](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/JavaLP/JavaToMac2/))

Comment: I know this but my code is not going to compile on Windows if I add an "import com.apple.eawt.*". Actually my problem is not exactly the integration, I also want my code to be compiled on Windows.

Comment: If you have the JAR file that contains the com.apple.* classes, you can compile on any platform.  I don't know which JAR it is, but you'll probably find it on your Mac somewhere.  You won't need the JAR at runtime if you do as Michael suggests and avoid using those classes on non-Apple platforms.  Anyway, the articles I linked to show that you can achieve quite a bit without needing any Apple classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few thing you can add at the beginning of your "main" function that will have your "swing" application look more native on MacOSX (works with 10.6 too)

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
System.setProperty("com.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name", "Your app name");
try {
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {}
catch (InstantiationException ex) {}
catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {}
catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {}
```

this will have your menu bar go in the mac menu bar. It will set your app name in the menu bar and will set your app look and feel to mac OSX l&f.

Its not perfect but it's a quick start :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have the code look at the OS-related [System properties](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) and only run the code when you see Mac OS X.

Comment: But the code is not going to compile on Windows if I add "import com.apple.eawt.*". Am I right?

Comment: You would have to run the code with reflection for it to compile.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful, and want to return the favor by updating. The "Mac OS X Integration for Java" web page has a link called "J2SE 5.0 Apple Extensions Reference" to the com.apple.eawt documentation that (as of Dec 2015) no longer works - says "Sorry, that page cannot be found". I tried searching the Apple Developer site for it without success. The good news is I found this link that has the source code for com.apple.eawt - http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt

Using com.apple.eawt, I found that the method removeAboutMenuItem() is deprecated and says to "use setAboutHandler(AboutHandler) with a null parameter" instead. But setAboutHandler(null) doesn't work, and the deprecated method does.